# Register script in one plugin, and enqueue it in another

Tags: plugins, wp-enqueue-script

I need to register a script in one plugin and enqueue it in another. This is not working the way I expect it would. Am I missing something?

Plugin that registers script:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_register_styles' );

function my_register_styles() {
        wp_register_style( 'fontawesome', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
        //wp_enqueue_style( 'fontawesome' ); // This works when uncommented.
}
```

Other plugin to enqueue script:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'other_register_styles' );

function my_register_styles() {
       wp_register_style( 'style', PATH . 'assets/css/style.min.css' );
       wp_enqueue_style( 'style' ); // Working as expected

       wp_enqueue_style( 'fontawesome' ); // Currently not working!
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prioritize your actions, so the register_style function runs first. (notice the third parameter in the add_action function)

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'other_register_styles', 11 );
function other_register_styles() {
       wp_register_style( 'style', PATH . 'assets/css/style.min.css' );
       wp_enqueue_style( 'style' ); // Working as expected

       wp_enqueue_style( 'fontawesome' ); // Currently not working!
}
```

The default priority is 10, so you just need to add 11 to other_register_styles.

Comment: Of course! That works wonderfully. Thank you for catching.